# Create a list of identical elements to the size of another list

Tags: racket

Let's say I have a `(list a b c d)` which has a length of 4.

I also have an object, say `(circle 4 "solid" "white")`.

I want to make a list of that object, to the length of the first list.

So end result would be:

```
(list (circle 4 "solid" "white") (circle 4 "solid" "white") (circle 4 "solid" "white") (circle 4 "solid" "white"))
```

I rather not use a loop or any higher-order function unless it's map or apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`make-list`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._make-list%29%29)

```
(make-list 4 'some-value)
; ==> (some-value some-value some-value some-value)
```

So if you want as many elements as some other list you just need to know the [`length`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=length#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._length%29%29)

```
(make-list (length other-list) (circle 4 "solid" "white"))
; ==> (#<object1> #<object1> #<object1> #<object1>)
```

Since `make-list` is a function it will evaluate the argument `(circle ...)` expression before it makes the list so that your list elements will point at the same object and not individually created objects. If you want that you can use `map`

```
(map (λ (ignored) (circle 4 "solid" "white")) other-list)
; ==> (#<object1> #<object2> #<object3> #<object4>)
```